# How to match a string with regex where specific character appears at least once so that the first neighbours characters are different from it?

Tags: regex

I'm searching for the shortest regex that can matches a string described in a question. I'm also interested in solution where regex matches string where specific character never appears surounded with same character.

This is currently my solution (in this case specific charcter is **g**):

```
^.*[^g]{1}g[^g]{1}.*$|^g[^g]{1}.*$|^.*[^g]{1}g$|^g$
```

I expect that regex matches strings like:`aaagaa`, `g`, `gdddg`, `agaagga`, `ggaaga`
,but doesn't matches: `aaagg`,`ggaagg`,`gg`, `ggg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to match at least one `g` with no adjacent `g`:

```
(?<!g)g(?!g)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AzTKu8/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!g)`: Assert that previous letter is not `g`
- `g`: Match a letter `g`
- `(?!g)`: Assert that next letter is not `g`

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't put this example: `ggaaga`.